# Task schedule IE 9 & force document mode to use IE 9 standards X-UA not functioning right

Tags: drupal-7, internet-explorer-9, x-ua-compatible

I'm running IE 9 in fullscreen through a scheduled task. However when IE 9 opens my website, it uses IE 7 standards by default. My website is using drupal 7.

I have my meta tag placed on the header already.

```
http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"
```

I'm using "-k" as a parameter to run IE on fullscreen, is there a equivalent parameter to force IE 9 to use IE 9 standards as document mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change compatibility view settings. IE->Tools->Compatibility View settings. There is no parameter to be used during startup.